# On finding a linear independent subset of vectors to describe a vector in a cone

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, convex-cone

Given a vector $b$ lying in the cone of a linear dependent set of vectors $a_1...a_n$. There exists a linear independent subset of vectors from $a_1...a_n$ such that $b$ lies in the cone of the subset.

I'm struggling to turn this into a rigorous proof.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?  Have you tried some simple examples?  For example, what happens if $a_{1}=(1,0)$ and $a_{2}=(1,1)$?

Comment: Actually, now, I don't think it is true for $R^n$, in general, after reading some information about positive bases, in higher dimensions. I still believe it is true in $R^2$.

Comment: That sounds like the cone version of Carathéodory’s theorem. See https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture2.pdf (theorem 18), for example.

Comment: @random thanks for your comment. Would you like to provide an answer with that so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the suggestion, but building a reputation from references is not my target.